# Filter data frame on last occurrence of non-NA value by group

Tags: r, dplyr

In this type of data:

```
df
   id Story Climax
1   1     A   <NA>
2   2     A      x
3   3     A   <NA>
4   4     A   <NA>
5   5     A      x
6   6     A      x  # <--- cut-off point
7   7     A   <NA>
8   8     B   <NA>
9   9     B   <NA>
10 10     B      y
11 11     B   <NA>
12 12     B      y  # <--- cut-off point
13 13     B   <NA>
14 14     B   <NA>
15 15     B   <NA>
```

I want to filter on last occurrence of non-`NA` value by group; i.e., I want to remove those rows per `Story` that are `NA` AND occur after the last non-`NA` value.

The desired output is this:

```
   id Story Climax
1   1     A   <NA>
2   2     A      x
3   3     A   <NA>
4   4     A   <NA>
5   5     A      x
6   6     A      x
8   8     B   <NA>
9   9     B   <NA>
10 10     B      y
11 11     B   <NA>
12 12     B      y
```

What I've tried so far is this, which however only filers **up until first occurrence of non-`NA`:

```
libraryr(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Story) %>%
  mutate(cnt = cumsum(!is.na(Climax))) %>%
  filter(cnt == 0)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:15,
  Story = c(rep("A",7), rep("B",8)),
  Climax = c(NA, "x", NA, NA, "x", "x", NA, NA, NA, "y", NA, "y", NA, NA, NA)
)
```

Comment: What about row 8 and 9? why should they be removed?

Comment: Yes, thanks so much for spotting this error: I've corrected it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution:

```
df %>%
   filter(max(which(!is.na(Climax)))>=row_number(), .by = Story)

   id Story Climax
1   1     A   <NA>
2   2     A      x
3   3     A   <NA>
4   4     A   <NA>
5   5     A      x
6   6     A      x
7   8     B   <NA>
8   9     B   <NA>
9  10     B      y
10 11     B   <NA>
11 12     B      y
```

Comment: Interesting! Can you comment on what is involved here?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, find the index of the last non NA value `max(which(!is.na(x)))`, then output all rows whose index is less or equal to this index. ie `index <= max(which(!is.na(x)))`

Comment: I like the simplicity of this; the only risk is that if `Climax` is all-`NA`, then this emits an error, whereas the other answers return 0 rows. I'm not knocking this: the error might be _a good thing_ to indicate your data is effectively empty, which might violate an assumption going-in. (It could be all-empty due to any number of reasons, including an "oops" earlier in your import, clean, etc.)

Comment: @r2evans yeah you are absolutely right. To incorporate that, one can add a `0` in the `max` function ie `max(which(!is.na(Climax)), 0)`. eg `df %>%add_case(Story = 'C') %>%filter(max(which(!is.na(Climax)),0)>=row_number(), .by = Story)` should work without warning/error

Answer (score 4):

The issue with your use of `cumsum` is that you're looking from the top-down, instead use `rev` to reverse it so we can look for the "first" from the bottom-up. I'll shift to using `dplyr::cumany` as well:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(Story) %>%
  filter(rev(cumany(!is.na(rev(Climax))))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 11 × 3
#       id Story Climax
#    <int> <chr> <chr> 
#  1     1 A     NA    
#  2     2 A     x     
#  3     3 A     NA    
#  4     4 A     NA    
#  5     5 A     x     
#  6     6 A     x     
#  7     8 B     NA    
#  8     9 B     NA    
#  9    10 B     y     
# 10    11 B     NA    
# 11    12 B     y
```

Answer (score 3):

You can count the cumulative sum of complete cases, and remove NAs after the last complete case.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Story) %>% 
  mutate(cumComplete = cumsum(complete.cases(Climax))) %>% 
  filter(!(cumComplete == max(cumComplete) & is.na(Climax))) %>% 
  select(-cumComplete)

#       id Story Climax
#  1     1 A     NA    
#  2     2 A     x     
#  3     3 A     NA    
#  4     4 A     NA    
#  5     5 A     x     
#  6     6 A     x     
#  7     8 B     NA    
#  8     9 B     NA    
#  9    10 B     y     
# 10    11 B     NA    
# 11    12 B     y
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R option using `subset` + `ave` + `rev`

```
> subset(df, ave(Climax, Story, FUN = \(x) rev(cumsum(rev(!is.na(x))))) > 0)
   id Story Climax
1   1     A   <NA>
2   2     A      x
3   3     A   <NA>
4   4     A   <NA>
5   5     A      x
6   6     A      x
8   8     B   <NA>
9   9     B   <NA>
10 10     B      y
11 11     B   <NA>
12 12     B      y
```

Another similar base R option but using `which` + `seq_along`

```
> subset(df, ave(!is.na(Climax), Story, FUN = \(x) seq_along(x) <= max(which(x))))
   id Story Climax
1   1     A   <NA>
2   2     A      x
3   3     A   <NA>
4   4     A   <NA>
5   5     A      x
6   6     A      x
8   8     B   <NA>
9   9     B   <NA>
10 10     B      y
11 11     B   <NA>
12 12     B      y
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following using `na.trim` from `zoo` package as well:

```
library(zoo)

do.call("rbind", by(df, df$Story, na.trim, sides = "right"))
```

**Output**

```
     id Story Climax
A.1   1     A   <NA>
A.2   2     A      x
A.3   3     A   <NA>
A.4   4     A   <NA>
A.5   5     A      x
A.6   6     A      x
B.8   8     B   <NA>
B.9   9     B   <NA>
B.10 10     B      y
B.11 11     B   <NA>
B.12 12     B      y
```